# Reconstructing a word

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, co.combinatorics

Let $w(a,b)$ be a word in two letter alphabet. Let $$A=\left(\begin{array}{lll}x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\\ x_4 &x_5 & x_6\\\ x_7 & x_8 & x_9\end{array}\right), B=\left(\begin{array}{lll}y_1 & y_2 & y_3\\\ y_4 &y_5 & y_6\\\ y_7 & y_8 & y_9\end{array}\right)$$ where $x_i,y_i$ are commuting variables. Let $f_w=\mathrm{trace}(w(A,B))$, a polynomial in 18 variables.

**Question.**  Is it possible to reconstruct $w$ up to a cyclic shift from $f_w$?

Note that there exists a polynomial in one variable that encodes $w$: $x^{p_1}+...+x^{p_s}+x^{|w|}$ where $p_1,...,p_s$ are the places where $a$ occurs in $w$. Also note that for 2 by 2 matrices the answer is "no". For example if $w=abbaba$ and $w'=ababba$, then $f_w=f_{w'}$ for 2 by 2 matrices. The question is related to the study of the moduli space of representations (of degree 3) of the free group.

**Update**  I think that as George suggested below, one can assume that $A=\mathrm{diag}(a,b,c)$ is a diagonal matrix (otherwise consider a conjugate of the pair $A,B$ over some algebraically complete field). After that the problem reduces to the following problem which seems longer but is in fact easier because we reduce the number of variables to from 18 to 3:

Pick a natural number $n\gg 1$. For every cyclic sequence $p$ (i.e. $p_{n+1}=p_1$) of $\{1,2,3\}$ of length $n$ consider a 9-vector 
$\phi(p)=($number of occurrences of 11, number of occurrences of 12, ..., number of occurrences of 33$)\in \mathbb{N}^9$.  The sum of coordinates of $\phi(p)$ is $n$, so we get a partition of $n$, and the number of different $\phi(p)$ is at most the number of partitions of $n$ into 9 parts, so less than $n^9$. Thus the map $\phi$ has a non-trivial kernel $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$ (i.e. the equivalence relation $p\equiv q$ iff $\phi(p)=\phi(q)$ ). Let $S$ be a preimage of a point in $\mathbb{N}^9$ under $\phi$. Let $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$ be a cyclic vector of natural numbers (including 0). For every $p\in S$ consider the monomial $m_p=a^sb^tc^u$ in  3 variables where $s$ is the sum of $v_i$ such that $p_i=1$, $t$ is the sum of $v_i$ such that $p_i=2$, $u$ is the sum of $v_i$ such that $p_i=3$. The sum of all the monomials $m_p$, $p\in S$, is a polynomial $f_S(v)$ in $a,b,c$. That polynomial is the coefficient of the monomial $\prod_{(i,j)} B[i,j]^{\phi(p)[i,j]}$ in $f_w$.

**Question**  Is the sequence $v$ determined by the sequence of polynomials $f_S(v)$ where $S$ runs over the equivalence classes of the partition $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$.

Comment: Basically your question amounts to asking if nonconjugate words are separated by characters of semisimple representations of degree 3. If the words have different length 1-dimensional representations suffice. So assume u is a word of length k. Then there are finitely many non conjugate words of length k. To each such word v one can look at the closed subvariety of all representations such that the traces for u,v coincide. By irreducibility one has to show this is a proper subvariety. So you are reduced to the following question: can any two nonconjugate words of the same length be separated

Comment: cts... by characters of 3-dim semisimple representations. 

Comment: That is correct but it makes the problem more complicated than it seems to be. One even can assume that the coefficients are modulo 2, so only the "tropical" data is available, the monomials that occur in $f_w$

Comment: $abbab$ and $babba$ are conjugate...

Comment: @Mikael: Yes, thanks! I have made a change. Now the words are not conjugate. In fact if $w'$ is the word $w$ written from right to left, then always $f_w=f_{w'}$ for 2 by 2 matrices. 

Comment: How many words have you recovered?  It seems likely that you could tease out (the presence of) substrings of the form a^k or b^l from the trace.  What length words can you recover?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 20012.07.23

Comment: @Gerhard: Any such info would be welcome. More precisely, I would like to see information like: if $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$ are consecutive positions of $a$ in $w$, then $p_{i+1}-p_i$ is encoded somewhere in $f_w$. That would give $w$ up to conjugation. 
  

Comment: You can see that $f_w$ determines $w$ up to cyclic shifts by looking at rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that only handles the characteristic 0 case.

Comment: @George: How can you prove it for char=0? Many rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are conjugate. 

Comment: @George: I think you forgot about the trace in the definition of the polynomial $f_w$. If not, I would like to see the proof. The problem is open in char 0. 

Comment: @Mark: Yes, this is trickier than I thought at first. You can find the set of distances between the b's in the word, and even the set of pairs of consecutive distances, but this is not enough.

Comment: @George: How can you find the set of distances between $b$'s? 

Comment: Take $A={\rm diag}(a_1,a_2,a_3)$. If there are $n > 2$ b's in the word, then then the pair $(r,s)$ appears as consecutive distances between b's iff a term $a_1^ta_2^ra_3^sb_{11}^{n-3}b_{12}b_{23}b_{31}$ appears in the trace.

Comment: @George: It is nice (I need to check it of course)!


Comment: @George: Yes, it is correct. Clearly much more information about the word is encoded in $f_w$. 

Comment: @George: I checked for all positive words with up to 300 $b$'s. All of them are determined by $f_w$. 

Comment: If the answer to your question were no, then by a result of Bre\v sar and Klep (Corollary 5.8, Tracial Nullstellens ̈\"atze, Notions of Positivity and the Geometry of Polynomials, Trends in Mathematics, 79–101) the difference of the two words would be a binomial in two non-commuting variables over the rational numbers which can be written as the sum of a non-trivial polynomial identity in two variables for $3\times 3$-matrices and a sum of commutators. In particular, the answer to your questions is yes if both words have length at most five.

Comment: @Markus: The answer is "yes" if the words are of length at most 400 - I can prove that. 

Comment: Looking at what happens with random matrices $A$ and $B$, on gets the following equivalent form of your question: remark that the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the words of length $n$. For two words of length $n$, $f_w=f_{w'}$ if and only if $\sum_{\pi \in S_n, \pi \cdot w=w'} 3^{c(\pi)} = \sum_{\pi \in S_n, \pi \cdot w=w} 3^{c(\pi)}$ where $c(\pi)$ is the number of cycles in the commutator of $\pi$ and the cycle $(1 2\dots n)$. Equivalently, iff $w-w'$ belongs to the kernel of $\sum_\pi 3^{c(\pi)} \pi$. 

Comment: @Mikael: I do not understand the statement but what does it give? Is the kernel trivial or not?


Comment: @Mark: I don't know.

Comment: What is the connection with $c(\pi)$? Why is the problem equivalent to the triviality of the kernel?
 

Comment: I formulated an easier looking question which is equivalent to this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103288/a-combinatorial-question

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, just an explanation of my comment.

Fix an integer $n$. Consider the Hilbert space $H=\ell^2(\{a,b\}^n)$ spanned by the words of length $n$ in $a$ and $b$. The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on $H$. For every permutation $\pi \in S_n$ consider $c(\pi)$, the number of cycles in $ \pi^{-1} \tau \pi \tau^{-1}$, where $\tau$ is the cycle $(1 2 \dots n)$. Consider the following operator on $H$:
$$T = \sum_{\pi \in S_n} 3^{c(\pi)} \pi.$$

The content of my comment was that for two words of length $n$, $f_w = f_{w'}$ if and only if $T(\delta_w - \delta_{w'})=0$. In particular, it would be sufficient to prove that the kernel of $T$ is just the kernel of $\sum_{k=1}^n \tau^k$ (= the functions on $\{a,b\}^n$ that sum to $0$ on each $\tau$-orbit) to answer positively Marks' question. Unfortunately I could not prove it.

Indeed, take $A$ and $B$ random with entries that are independant centered complex gaussians with variance $1$ (the real and imaginary parts are real gaussians centered with variance $1/2$). Then 
`\[ \mathbb E[f_w(A,B) \overline{f_{w'}(A,B)}] = \langle T \delta_w, \delta_{w'}\rangle.\]`
This formula implies that $T$ is a non-negative operator, and that $f_w \mapsto  \sqrt T \delta_\omega$ is an isometry from the subspace of $L^2$ spanned by the $f_w$'s to $H$, and hence that $f_w = f_{w'}$ iff $\sqrt T \delta_w = \sqrt T \delta_{w'}$ iff $T \delta_w =  T \delta_{w'}$.

I am not sure it is worth writing a precise proof of this equality: if one developps the LHS of the inequality, on gets a big sum of moments of gaussians. To simplify this expression, use some moment-cumulant transformation which yields to the RHS. I can at least say that $3^{c(\pi)}$ appears as the number of pairs of $n$-uples $(i_1,\dots,i_n)$ and $(j_1,\dots j_n)$ such that $(i_k,i_{k+1}) = (j_{\pi(k)},j_{\pi(k)+1})$.